Нестандартное "hello world!"
Наткнулся на задачу в codewars где нужно было написать "hello world!" , вот что вышло но проблема в том , что codewars  не пропускает ее .В чем может быть дело?
Все что входит в первые два let это ASCII
function greet() {
  let hell = String.fromCharCode(72, 69, 76, 76, 79);
  let worl = String.fromCharCode(87, 79, 82, 76, 68, 33);
  let hell1 = hell.toLowerCase();
  let worl1 = worl.toLowerCase();
  let hellworl = `${hell1} ${worl1} `;
  return hellworl
}
   


Спрашивайте у codewars, наверное?

попробуйте убрать пробел в строке, там у них строго строка должна совпадать, а у вас https://i.sstatic.net/eLcRaDvI.png => ${hell1} ${worl1} тут у вас пробел

ну хоть бы ссылку на задачу или условия

Возможно дело в том, что у вас в строке в конце присутствует пробел, а codewars ищет точное совпадение, поэтому hello world <> hello world 

Спасибо , так и есть.
